# not able to get a link while web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to do web scraping using Python, on a page when 'T20I' is selected. For that, I need to put a specific link in requests and beautifulsoup.

whenever I open https://www.espncricinfo.com/cricketers/team/india-6 this link, I get a page with "INTL" selected.

Image with "INTL" selected:
[image]

But when I select "T20I", I get a different page but with similar link  https://www.espncricinfo.com/cricketers/team/india-6

image with "T20I" selected:
[image]

Then what should I do in this situation to retrieve the data? How will I get data when "T20I" is selected?

Comment: Use selenium to do web scrapping

Comment: When u selected T20I. You need to enter URL address  https://www.espncricinfo.com/cricketers/team/india-6/caps/twenty20-international-3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Selenium
Here is the example which can work just fine

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
browser =webdriver.Chrome(r"YOUR chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)


browser.get("https://www.espncricinfo.com/cricketers/team/india-6")
#find element you want to click by XPATH
button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-container"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/a/span/span')
#click the button "T20I"
button.click()
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Data is rendered through javascript. There is an api that pulls that. Don't use Selenium when there is an api.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://hs-consumer-api.espncricinfo.com/v1/pages/player/search'
payload = {
    'mode': 'BOTH',
    'page': '1',
    'records': '40',
    'filterActive': 'true',
    'filterTeamId': '6',
    'filterClassId': '3',
    'filterFormatLevel': 'ALL',
    'sort': 'ALPHA_ASC'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['results'])
```

**Output: 1st 5 rows of 31 rows**

```
print(df.head().to_string())
       id  objectId            name             longName  mobileName       indexName     battingName    fieldingName                 slug                              imageUrl                              dateOfBirth dateOfDeath gender battingStyles bowlingStyles longBattingStyles        longBowlingStyles                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      image  countryTeamId playerRoleTypeIds          playingRoles                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            headshotImage
0  101430   1125976  Arshdeep Singh       Arshdeep Singh              Arshdeep Singh  Arshdeep Singh  Arshdeep Singh       arshdeep-singh  /db/PICTURES/CMS/356700/356795.1.png    {'year': 1999, 'month': 2, 'date': 5}        None      M         [lhb]         [lmf]   [left-hand bat]   [left-arm medium-fast]  {'id': 356795, 'objectId': 1365005, 'slug': 'arshdeep-singh-player-portrait', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/356700/356795.1.png', 'width': 160, 'height': 213, 'caption': 'Arshdeep Singh player portrait', 'longCaption': 'Arshdeep Singh player portrait', 'credit': 'Getty Images', 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': None}              6               [4]              [bowler]        {'id': 322178, 'objectId': 1264653, 'slug': 'arshdeep-singh-player-page-headshot-cutout-2021', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/322100/322178.png', 'width': 600, 'height': 436, 'caption': 'Arshdeep Singh player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'longCaption': 'Arshdeep Singh player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'credit': None, 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': {'FILM': None, 'WIDE': None, 'SQUARE': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/322100/322178.square.png'}}
1   12894     26421        R Ashwin  Ravichandran Ashwin      Ashwin       Ashwin, R        R Ashwin          Ashwin  ravichandran-ashwin    /db/PICTURES/CMS/302300/302395.jpg   {'year': 1986, 'month': 9, 'date': 17}        None      M         [rhb]          [ob]  [right-hand bat]     [right-arm offbreak]                               {'id': 302395, 'objectId': 1220592, 'slug': 'r-ashwin-portrait', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/302300/302395.jpg', 'width': 160, 'height': 200, 'caption': 'R Ashwin portrait', 'longCaption': 'R Ashwin portrait, April 2020', 'credit': 'Getty Images', 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': None}              6              [11]  [bowling allrounder]                                                                                                                                           {'id': 316521, 'objectId': 1251150, 'slug': 'r-ashwin-headshot', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/316500/316521.png', 'width': 600, 'height': 436, 'caption': 'R Ashwin headshot', 'longCaption': 'R Ashwin headshot', 'credit': None, 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': {'FILM': None, 'WIDE': None, 'SQUARE': None}}
2   73507    694211      Avesh Khan           Avesh Khan  Avesh Khan      Avesh Khan      Avesh Khan      Avesh Khan           avesh-khan  /db/PICTURES/CMS/200000/200065.1.jpg  {'year': 1996, 'month': 12, 'date': 13}        None      M         [rhb]         [rfm]  [right-hand bat]  [right-arm fast-medium]                             {'id': 200065, 'objectId': 807641, 'slug': 'avesh-khan-portrait', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/200000/200065.1.jpg', 'width': 160, 'height': 200, 'caption': 'Avesh Khan portrait', 'longCaption': 'Avesh Khan portrait, November 2014', 'credit': 'MPCA', 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': None}              6               [4]              [bowler]                    {'id': 322244, 'objectId': 1264747, 'slug': 'avesh-khan-player-page-headshot-cutout-2021', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/322200/322244.png', 'width': 600, 'height': 436, 'caption': 'Avesh Khan player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'longCaption': 'Avesh Khan player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'credit': None, 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': {'FILM': None, 'WIDE': None, 'SQUARE': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/322200/322244.square.png'}}
3   70640    625383       JJ Bumrah       Jasprit Bumrah      Bumrah      Bumrah, JJ       JJ Bumrah          Bumrah       jasprit-bumrah  /db/PICTURES/CMS/356800/356849.1.png   {'year': 1993, 'month': 12, 'date': 6}        None      M         [rhb]          [rf]  [right-hand bat]         [right-arm fast]                          {'id': 356849, 'objectId': 1365132, 'slug': 'bumrah-player-portrait', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/356800/356849.1.png', 'width': 160, 'height': 206, 'caption': 'Bumrah player portrait', 'longCaption': 'Bumrah player portrait', 'credit': 'Getty Images', 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': None}              6               [4]              [bowler]        {'id': 319940, 'objectId': 1260219, 'slug': 'jasprit-bumrah-player-page-headshot-cutout-2021', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/319900/319940.png', 'width': 600, 'height': 436, 'caption': 'Jasprit Bumrah player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'longCaption': 'Jasprit Bumrah player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'credit': None, 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': {'FILM': None, 'WIDE': None, 'SQUARE': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/319900/319940.square.png'}}
4   61325    430246       YS Chahal     Yuzvendra Chahal      Chahal      Chahal, YS       YS Chahal          Chahal     yuzvendra-chahal    /db/PICTURES/CMS/312100/312155.png   {'year': 1990, 'month': 7, 'date': 23}        None      M         [rhb]         [lbg]  [right-hand bat]        [legbreak googly]    {'id': 312155, 'objectId': 1239214, 'slug': 'yuzvendra-chahal-portrait', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/312100/312155.png', 'width': 160, 'height': 200, 'caption': 'Yuzvendra Chahal portrait', 'longCaption': 'Yuzvendra Chahal portrait, November 2020', 'credit': 'Getty Images', 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': None}              6               [4]              [bowler]  {'id': 319955, 'objectId': 1260243, 'slug': 'yuzvendra-chahal-player-page-headshot-cutout-2021', 'url': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/319900/319955.png', 'width': 600, 'height': 436, 'caption': 'Yuzvendra Chahal player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'longCaption': 'Yuzvendra Chahal player page headshot cutout, 2021', 'credit': None, 'photographer': None, 'peerUrls': {'FILM': None, 'WIDE': None, 'SQUARE': '/db/PICTURES/CMS/319900/319955.square.png'}}
```